# Error when trying to get info from current session user. "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React/Node and working on a learning project. It's a platform that connects users (freelancers) with nonprofit companies. When a user logs in, they can view a list of companies and click a button to connect with that company. They can then go to the UserConnections page to view all the companies they're connected with.

When they click the 'connect' button, the connection is made in the database, and the button becomes disabled. This is currently working correctly.. unless you refresh the page, in which case the button becomes clickable again.

To fix this, I have access to `currentUser.connections`. Console logging this gives me an array of the company handles that the user is connected to. I would like to check if the company the user is currently viewing is on this list or not. If it is, update the `connected` state to `true`. So I added this code:

```
if (currentUser.connections.includes(companyHandle)) {
      setConnected(true);
    }
```

Adding the above code produces this error: `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

How can I do this without triggering this error? Code is below (shortened):

**CompanyDetail.js**

```
function CompanyDetail() {
  const { companyHandle } = useParams();
  const [company, setCompany] = useState(null);
  const { currentUser, hasConnectedToCompany, connectToCompany } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState();


  React.useEffect(function updateConnectedStatus() {
    setConnected(hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle));
  }, [companyHandle, hasConnectedToCompany]);


  async function handleConnect(evt) {
    if (hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle)) return;
    connectToCompany(companyHandle);
    setConnected(true);

    let connectUserInDb;
    try {
      connectUserInDb = await VolunteerApi.connectToCompany(currentUser.username, companyHandle);
    } catch (err) {
      setFormErrors(err);
      return;
    }
  }

  if (currentUser) {
    if (currentUser.connections.includes(companyHandle)) {
      setConnected(true);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1> {company.companyName} </h1>
          <p>
            <button onClick={handleConnect} disabled={connected}> {connected ? "Connected" : "Connect"} </button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1> {company.companyName} </h1>
          <p>
            <a href="/login-user"><button>Login to Connect</button></a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it triggers too many re-renders is because you are calling a setter state function in the render scope; updating a useState variable causes a re-render.

The logic:

```
if (currentUser.connections.includes(companyHandle)) {
  setConnected(true);
}
```

Should go into an useEffect:

```
useEffect(() > {
   if (currentUser.connections.includes(companyHandle)) {
      setConnected(true);
    }
}, [currentUserConnectionHash, companyHandle]);
```

By doing so, the effect (and related setState) will be called only when `companyHandle` and `currentUser.connections` change.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I want to do this only if there is a logged in user. If I do something like `if (currentUser) { useEffect(().. }`, I get an error because I'm using `useEffect` conditionally. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem! Happy you figure it out :)